# makeStyles of MUI not loading after reload in nextjs application

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui, makestyles

when i start the development server all the styles are properly loaded but gone after reload. I'm using nextJs and this problem is due to SSR of nextJs. I know but can't configure properly and need help. I added _document.js, created emotioncache file and updated _app.js.
But after all this may be something is missing.

my _app.js file

```
import { CacheProvider } from '@emotion/react';
import { ThemeProvider, CssBaseline } from '@mui/material';

import createEmotionCache from '../utility/createEmotionCache';
import lightTheme from '../styles/theme/lightTheme';
import Navbar from '@/components/Navbar';
import Drawer from '@/components/Drawer';
import { Stack, Box } from '@mui/material';
import '@/styles/globals.css';


const clientSideEmotionCache = createEmotionCache();

export default function App(props) {

  const { Component, emotionCache = clientSideEmotionCache, pageProps } = props;

  return (
    <CacheProvider value={emotionCache}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={lightTheme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <Box sx={{ height: '100vh', overflow: 'hidden' }}>
          <Navbar />
          <Stack direction="row" spacing={3} sx={{ marginTop: '8px' }}>
            <Drawer />
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </Stack>
        </Box>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </CacheProvider>
  )
}
```

my document.js file

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';
import createEmotionServer from '@emotion/server/create-instance';
import createEmotionCache from '../utility/createEmotionCache';

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="en">
        <Head>
          <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap"
          />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

// `getInitialProps` belongs to `_document` (instead of `_app`),
// it's compatible with static-site generation (SSG).
MyDocument.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  // Resolution order
  //
  // On the server:
  // 1. app.getInitialProps
  // 2. page.getInitialProps
  // 3. document.getInitialProps
  // 4. app.render
  // 5. page.render
  // 6. document.render
  //
  // On the server with error:
  // 1. document.getInitialProps
  // 2. app.render
  // 3. page.render
  // 4. document.render
  //
  // On the client
  // 1. app.getInitialProps
  // 2. page.getInitialProps
  // 3. app.render
  // 4. page.render

  const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

  // You can consider sharing the same emotion cache between all the SSR requests to speed up performance.
  // However, be aware that it can have global side effects.
  const cache = createEmotionCache();
  const { extractCriticalToChunks } = createEmotionServer(cache);

  /* eslint-disable */
  ctx.renderPage = () =>
    originalRenderPage({
      enhanceApp: (App) =>
        function EnhanceApp(props) {
          return <App emotionCache={cache} {...props} />;
        },
    });
  /* eslint-enable */

  const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
  // This is important. It prevents emotion to render invalid HTML.
  // See https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/26561#issuecomment-855286153
  const emotionStyles = extractCriticalToChunks(initialProps.html);
  const emotionStyleTags = emotionStyles.styles.map((style) => (
    <style
      data-emotion={`${style.key} ${style.ids.join(' ')}`}
      key={style.key}
      // eslint-disable-next-line react/no-danger
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: style.css }}
    />
  ));

  return {
    ...initialProps,
    // Styles fragment is rendered after the app and page rendering finish.
    styles: [
      ...React.Children.toArray(initialProps.styles),
      ...emotionStyleTags,
    ],
  };
};
```

createEmotionCache file

```
import createCache from '@emotion/cache';

const createEmotionCache = () => {
  return createCache({ key: 'css', prepend: true });
};

export default createEmotionCache;
```

also added a theme.js

```
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

const lightTheme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    mode: 'light',
  },
});

export default lightTheme;
```

my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "new",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/cache": "^11.10.7",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.6",
    "@emotion/server": "^11.10.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.6",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.16",
    "@mui/material": "^5.12.0",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.12.0",
    "axios": "^1.3.6",
    "eslint": "8.38.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.3.0",
    "next": "13.3.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  }
}
```

this is navigation bar component using makestyles.

```
import React from 'react'
import { AppBar, Box, Stack, Toolbar, IconButton, Typography, Icon } from '@mui/material'
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';


//Icons 
import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';
import YouTubeIcon from '@mui/icons-material/YouTube';
import ClearIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Clear';
import SearchIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Search';
import MicIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Mic';
import VideoCallIcon from '@mui/icons-material/VideoCall';
import NotificationsNoneIcon from '@mui/icons-material/NotificationsNone';

//CSS Styles 
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  appbar: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    color: 'black',
    boxShadow: 'none',
    height: '50px',
    display: 'flex',
    position: 'relative',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  toolbar: {
    height: '50px',
    padding: '0px 8px',
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
  searchbar: {
    height: '30px',
    padding: '0px 0px 0px 12px',
    border: '1px solid rgba(184, 179, 179, 0.295)',
    borderRight: 'none',
    borderRadius: '30px 0px 0px 30px',
    width: '500px',
    '&:focus': {
      outline: 'none',
    },
    '&::placeholder': {
      color: 'rgba(48, 46, 46, 0.295)',
      fontSize: '14px',
    }
  },
  searchwrapper: {
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  searchbutton: {
    height: '30px',
    padding: '0px 12px 0px 8px',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    border: '1px solid rgba(184, 179, 179, 0.295)',
    borderRadius: '0px 30px 30px 0px',
    background: 'rgba(184, 179, 179, 0.295)'
  }
}));

const NavMain = () => {
  return (
    <Stack direction="row" spacing={0.8} alignItems="center">
      <IconButton >
        <MenuIcon sx={{ fontSize: '28px', color: 'black' }} />
      </IconButton>
      <IconButton>
        <YouTubeIcon sx={{ fontSize: '28px', color: 'red' }} />
        <Typography variant="h6">Youtube</Typography>
      </IconButton>
    </Stack>
  );
}

const NavSearch = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Stack direction="row" spacing={0.8} alignItems="center" sx={{ marginLeft: '120px' }}>
      <div className={classes.searchwrapper}>
        <input
          placeholder='Search'
          className={classes.searchbar}
        />
        <Icon className={classes.searchbutton} >
          <SearchIcon />
        </Icon>
      </div>
      <IconButton>
        <MicIcon sx={{ color: 'black' }} />
      </IconButton>
    </Stack>
  );
}

const NavEnd = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Stack direction="row" spacing={1} alignItems="center">
      <IconButton>
        <VideoCallIcon sx={{ color: 'black' }} />
      </IconButton>
      <IconButton>
        <NotificationsNoneIcon sx={{ color: 'black' }} />
      </IconButton>
      {/* <Icon>

      </Icon> */}
    </Stack>
  )
}

const Navbar = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <AppBar className={classes.appbar}>
      <Toolbar className={classes.toolbar}>
        <NavMain />
        <NavSearch />
        <NavEnd />
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
  )
}

export default Navbar;
```

notice that after reload only styles are gone rest html and js are there.